# Calculating selling price given margin + tax for tax inclusive pricing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the following:

- Cost price of an item is 100.00 (**NOT including tax**)
- Margin of 10%
- Tax of 8%

What is the formula for finding the selling price that will meet these requirements? The final selling price **INCLUDES tax** of 8% and the margin must be 10%.

The selling price in the example above is 118.80 (I came up with this via guessing).

The tax on 118.80 is 8.80 leaving a margin of 10%.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by doing:

```
    var X = cost_price;
    var Y = margin_percent;
    var Q = tax_percent;

    var margin_price = (Q*X*Y+100*Q*X+100*X*Y+10000*X)/10000;
```

This is probably not the best way to do it; but this is what I came up with... My algebra skills are a bit rusty so there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

Selling price = 100/(1-0,10)/(1-0,08) = 120,7729

Now:

Tax = 120,7729 * 0,08 = 9,6618

Margin = (120,7729-9,6618) * 0,10 = 111,1111 * 0,10 = 11,1111